# Sentencing guidelines for Regulation of Investigatory Powers Act 2000 (RIPA)

Tags: criminal-law, england-and-wales, common-law, encryption

I have read into [section 49](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2000/23/section/49) of the **Regulation of Investigatory Powers Act 2000 (RIPA)** which can demand suspects surrender passwords for encrypted devices, and [section 53](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2000/23/section/53) makes it an offence not to do so when compelled.

I am confused as to why I was unable to find the **sentencing guidelines** for the above **RIPA** offences, to better understand how a judge would make a decision as to the sentence, and type of sentence (suspended, community order, immediate custodial etc...).

Why do some offences not appear on the sentencing guidelines website?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The statutory requirement for sentencing guidelines are at [section 120](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2009/25/section/120?timeline=false) Coroners and Justice Act 2009, which includes:

> (2) A sentencing guideline **may be general in nature** or limited to a particular offence, particular category of offence or particular category of offender.

Therefore, not every offence etc requires - or has - its own specific sentencing guideline. (*Presumably as there are far too many offences to easily cover, so limited resources might need to be focused on the more common ones*.)

Note that at the foot of the Sentencing Council's [explantory materials](https://www.sentencingcouncil.org.uk/explanatory-material/magistrates-court/item/using-the-mcsg/using-sentencing-council-guidelines/) is this link:

> Where there is no guideline for an offence, refer to the [General guideline.](https://www.sentencingcouncil.org.uk/overarching-guides/magistrates-court/item/general-guideline-overarching-principles/)

Which states it is for:

> sentencing offences for which there is no offence specific sentencing guideline...

So this General guideline is the one to be applied when dealing with a s.53 RIPA offence. (*I've not reproduced it here to save space*)